# Implementing operator

Tags: r, operators

I need to implement operator %in%, which gives TRUE if point on the left is in the list on the right and gives FALSE in opposite case. Problem is that i cannot use a loop and any extra packages.

**Creating a list**

```
ell <- list( 2, c( 2, 5), list( c( 2, 8)), "test")
```

**Elements in list**

- `2`
- `c(2, 5)`
- `list(c(2, 8))`
- `"test"`

---

**Testing elements**

```
2 %in% ell
# TRUE

5 %in% ell
# FALSE

list(c(2, 8)) %in% ell
# TRUE

list(list(2, 8)) %in% ell
# FALSE

"test" %in% ell
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%in%` is an operator that identifies whether the first argument is the subset of the second one. So the ability you expected cannot be achieved by `%in%`. Here is another solution to get what you want by `sapply()`. For example:

```
any(sapply(ell, identical, list(c( 2, 8))))
# [1] TRUE
any(sapply(ell, identical, list(list( 2, 8))))
# [1] FALSE
```

---

You can define a custom operator by yourself to implement the method above. I name it `%IN%`:

```
`%IN%` <- function(a, b){
  any(sapply(b, identical, a))
}

2 %IN% ell
# [1] TRUE
5 %IN% ell
# [1] FALSE
list(c(2, 8)) %IN% ell
# [1] TRUE
list(list(2, 8)) %IN% ell
# [1] FALSE
"test" %IN% ell
# [1] TRUE
```